# Is there a way to convert a regular address to an ICAP address?

Tags: accounts, addresses, icap

The [ethkey guide](https://gavofyork.gitbooks.io/turboethereum/content/ethkey.html) mentions how a regular address can be obtained from an ICAP address.  But it doesn't mention how an ICAP address can be obtained from a regular address.

> Occasionally, however, it's important to convert between the two.
>   ethkey provides the inspect command for this purpose. When passed any
>   address, file or UUID, it will tell you information about it including
>   both formats of address.

Since most people already have regular hex addresses, can they be converted to ICAP without having to create new private keys?  Or is there a way to use ICAP without needing to create a new ICAP address and sweeping the funds to this new address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is discussed here: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/ICAP:-Inter-exchange-Client-Address-Protocol

It seems that a "basic" ICAP address can be created from any pre-existing hex address, but only accounts with hex addresses that fit into 154 bits can be represented with "direct" ICAP addresses.